# Language-based review tasks

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review, languages

There are already some good review tasks on Stack Exchange (like First Posts, Late Answer...), but I think another review task feature would be nice.

**Consider this** 

Lots of people here aren't native English and some of them can't ask their own question very well in English. If there was a tag or something that they could add to their question so other people who speaks their language could understand what they want, and modify the question.

I know there is already Stack Overflow in other languages, but a localized Stack Overflow won't help much because there are lots of other experts that could answer your question in English, not in your mother language.

---

It happened to me several times on Stack Overflow:

Some young student asks a very unclear question and when I see their profile that they speak [Farsi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language), I leave a Farsi comment for them, and they could ask their question very clearly in Farsi.

Comment: What else should we support? All languages? How are we to ensure all languages get a prompt response from the community? How are we to determine what should go into such a queue?

Comment: You dont need to support any other languages, also you cant ensure all languages even get response, but  you could be sure that users question from some languages will be fixed sooner and will get proper answers instead of getting close for being unclear.

Comment: @Oded to answering your last question, there are three approach in my opinion:
First let the user decide, when someone cant speak English he can understand that the question he asked is crap, so he could use a help tag or raise a flag for help.
another way is to add another flag to our current flag, some flag like not understandable english or .... so we could move flaged post to the queue.
Third way is to move question to this queues regarding to user history, reputation and the place he/she mentioned in his/her profile.

Comment: Maar krijg je dan commentaar en nieuwe versies in verschillende talen? Dat is toch verwarrend?

Comment: @rene Het is beter dan niets :D

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but isn't that an editor's job?  Sure it would sort out stuff, but poor English questions sorta contribute to about 1/3 of my rep gain on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is really hard to implement this. Not only should the question be translated, but all of the answers too, and the updates to the answers. Otherwise, the user asking the question can't understand the answer...

Although I understand your problem, I think it is better to go the path Stack Exchange is going now: one site per language.

The advantage of this approach is that it is clear what language the site demands. Keeping translating questions, answers or even comments, etc. is a lot of work, which has to be done in many, many languages. Think of the infrastructure necessary to do this and the need for version control on questions and answers. (Even Wikipedia has a per-language page, although it is much better suited for translation!)

If you want to use Stack Overflow in English for its experts, you could probably use a browser with a built-in translator.

Comment: No it is not like that, writing in a foreign language in very harder than reading it, in must case, people could read english very well but cant ask their exact problem here.

Comment: So we should translate comments too? And edits? And what if the translator didn't do a very good job? The answers will be incomplete, or even totally wrong...

Comment: No there is no need to translate comments, answers , .... All I'm saying is mark the question that are unclear obviously because of the asker's poor english and the people with same language try to make them more readable, users still should ask their question in english not in any other languages!